# Jacoco code coverage Android Studio not consider androidTest folder

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I'm trying to activate Jacoco on my Android project, both for Unit Tests, (`test` folder) and for instrumented tests (`androidTest` folder). Really I am most interested to instrumented test, because my test are placed here.

I can execute both types of tests with success, but when I try to create the coverage report (with the `gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` command) the instrumented tests were not considerated.

Also, when I right-click on the folders, only the tests inside `test` folder display the "run with Coverage" option, and if I go to "Edit configuration" only the configurations under JUnit have the "Code Coverage" tab, not seen it in "Android Tests" configurations.

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: "jacoco"

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
//        testInstrumentationRunner 'com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testCoverageEnabled false
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

productFlavors {
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
//        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'NOTICE'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'LICENSE'
    exclude 'asm-license.txt'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
// Optional -- Hamcrest library
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
//    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
//    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
//    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
//    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'

androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**gradlew createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport** creates code coverage report for instrumented tests in the app module which you can find it in

> /build/reports/coverage/debug > index.html